# Help with LAMMPS create_atoms and delete_atoms command

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps

I am running polymer simulations inside a spherical region. I have loaded the polymer using read_data command. I want to add fixed number of individual new atom types inside this sphere while it avoids the polymer.

```
log            ./atom_create.out
lattice        fcc 0.85
units          lj
atom_style     full
boundary       f f f

read_data     ./case_1/1/polymer_centered.input

region         outerbox sphere 0.0 0.0 0.0 8.0 side in units box

create_atoms   3 region outerbox
```

This fills the fcc points inside the sphere and gives no control on how many atoms to add. I have tried doing

`create_atoms   3 random 100 0413 outerbox overlap 1.0 maxtry 50`

but I get an error - illegal create_atoms command. Is there  a way to avoid the polymer while adding new atoms?

Comment: Please state the LAMMPS version (listed in the first line of the log file), and try removing the leading `0` from `0413` as that may be preventing LAMMPS from recognising it as a valid whole number for the RNG seed.

Comment: @ShernRenTee I am using 29 Sep 2021 - Update 2 version which i installed from the linux mint repositories.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.lammps.org/create_atoms.html) says `random` was only added to `create_atoms` in the 2Jun2022 version. So you need to use the latest version. LAMMPS is relatively easy to compile from source.

Comment: @ShernRenTee Thank you. Upon removal of overlap and maxtry the addition of random atom works for 2021 version. I have built the 2023 version and it runs as intended.